# How to find out which function in asp.net has memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a asp.net web application which seems to crash IIS 7.0. The reason I say this is the application works for 16 hours with new issues and every 16 hours approx, it needs IIS RESET.

Is there any tool or method we can find out what's (e.g. ado.net, dll etc)causing the memory leak in web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like ANTS Profiler:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=antsmemoryprofiler&gclid=CJDh64au2LICFeTKtAodMgYAbQ

I think is what you need.

You can download a free trial of it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Memory Profiler`, you can also use `MiniProfiler`

Link : http://memprofiler.com/?gclid=CJy414qu2LICFcPHtAodkkkABQ

Link : http://miniprofiler.com/